# Como fazer validação em formulários HTML

Tags: html, validação

Como são feitos os campos obrigatórios em formulários HTML (aqueles que comumente usam um asterisco `*` para indicar obrigatoriedade)? Há algum parâmetro diretamente na tag `input`? Se não, como é feita a validação (por exemplo, no momento em que o usuário clica em enviar, se o campo não foi preenchido uma mensagem é exibida e o formulário não é enviado)?

Comment: Gonçalo, a sua pergunta andou recebendo votos para ser fechada como não clara, provavelmente pela forma como você escreveu. Tomei a liberdade de editá-la para tentar ajudar. Lembre-se sempre que vc mesmo pode editar pra tentar melhorar (ao receber um negativo ou um voto pra fechar), ok? :) Boa sorte.

Comment: Dependo do navegador a validação  apenas com HTML não vai funcionar. O ideal é que a validação seja feita via javascript com  uma validação mais robusta correndo em segundo plano com uma linguagem web(php,java,c#...)

Comment: Obrigado Luiz. Desculpe pelo incomodo.

Comment: entendo porque você talvez não tenha encontrado esta outra pergunta, mas vou deixar ela aqui para referências futuras: [Restrição input "type date"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119873/41113)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o atributo required:

```
<input type="text" name="obrigatorio" required>
```

Abcs!

Comment: **(atenção: vc já ganhou o meu +1 e eu também votei e comentei o mesmo na outra resposta existente)**. Seria muito importante para referência futura de outros usuários se vc descrevesse também qual é o suporte dessa tag nos navegadores. Talvez até fornecendo uma alternativa em Javascript para o caso em que a tag não seja suportada. Se fizer uma resposta bacana nesses moldes, eu até ofereço uma recompensa por ela. :)

Answer (score 3):

Basta pores o required na tag do input

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: **(atenção: vc já ganhou o meu +1 e eu também votei e comentei o mesmo na outra resposta existente)**. Seria muito importante para referência futura de outros usuários se vc descrevesse também qual é o suporte dessa tag nos navegadores. Talvez até fornecendo uma alternativa em Javascript para o caso em que a tag não seja suportada. Se fizer uma resposta bacana nesses moldes, eu até ofereço uma recompensa por ela. :)