# Restrição input "type date"

Tags: html5

Código:

```
<input type="date" name="data" value="">
<input type="submit" class="success round button" value=""/>
```

Preciso que quando eu clique no botão submit e o campo date estiver em branco ele não me deixe enviar. Tem algum modo no html mesmo sem ser JS para fazer essa restrição ?

Comment: Já testaste juntando o atributo `required`? Assim: https://jsfiddle.net/spz8txma/

Comment: É verdade rs, era só isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o atributo [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) que é exatamente para evitar que o campo seja enviado vazio. Essa funcionalidade da API de HTML5 é [suportada praticamente em todos os browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation).

Ficaria assim:

```
<input type="date" name="data" value="" required>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spz8txma/